# How to make a RSL with Flash CS5.5?

Tags: flash, swc, rsl, flash-cs5.5

Is it possible to make a RSL with Flash Professional? I've tried it in the past before CS5.5 was released with no success, and lately wanted to try it again in order to make some tests, but it seems it's not possible.

I know plain SWCs can be built, but everything I've tried results in a library that must be merged into the main file.

Answer (score 0):

Dude, from what I understand you must use the SWC as an external file and the code within the code to load the SWF this SWC.

The SWC will only be used to reference the classes in the project that will use Flash. Within your project you must load the external classes this way: http://old-wp.slekx.com/2010/01/flash-cs4-runtime-shared-library-tutorial/

Other example: http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/contentdomains/?page=2

This is a solution that will use because I'm having the same problem.